# Unable to display in Chrome [object Object] in GET request with Angular

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, mean-stack

I am build application that sends a GET request to a server, receives a list of items as a response and displays them on the page. I can see values in console, but in chrome instead of values i see [object][Object],[object][Object].

task.components.ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {TaskService } from '../../services/task.service';
import { Task } from '../../../../Task';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-tasks',
  templateUrl: './tasks.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./tasks.component.css']
})
export class TasksComponent  {
  tasks: Task[];
  constructor(private taskService: TaskService) {
    this.taskService.getTaskProducts()
    .subscribe(tasks => {
      console.log(' tasks are :', this.tasks);

      const finalArray = [];
      Object.keys(tasks).forEach(key =>
        finalArray.push(tasks[key]));
      this.tasks = finalArray;
      console.log(' tasks are :', this.tasks);
   });
  }
  }
```

I have created Task.ts file :

```
export class Task {
  titile: string;
  isDone: boolean;
}
```

tasks.component.html :

```
    <form class="well">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Add tasks here">
  </div>
  </form>
  <div class = "task-list">
set task : {{tasks}}
    <div *ngFor ="let task of tasks">
    <div class="col-md-1">
      <input type="checkbox">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-7">
      some tasks  :
      {{task}}
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary a-btn-slide-text">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span><strong>Edit</strong></span>
    </a></div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

output is :

welcome to Courier Services
Add tasks here
set task : [object Object],[object Object],[object Object]

some tasks : [object Object]

some tasks : [object Object]

some tasks : [object Object]

instead of values i am getting as[object][Object], please help me in solving this. thanks in advance.

Comment: You try to show objects, whereas you need to show strings in template. So pick what you want to show inside the object, instead of just outputting the whole object.

Comment: Or just `JSON.stringify` it if you want to see the whole object.

Comment: Where did you declare `taskss`?

Comment: Show the value of `console.log(' tasks are :', this.tasks);` line?

Comment: In my console i can see values : 

 tasks are : (3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]0: isDone: falsetitle: "walk the dog"_id: "5cac8bbdfb6fc01d56637c2d"__proto__: Object1: isDone: falsetitle: "go food shopping"_id: "5cac8c2ffb6fc01d56637c84"__proto__: Object2: isDone: falsetitle: "read a book"_id: "5cac8c55fb6fc01d56637ca3"__proto__: Objectlength: 3__proto__: Array(0)


 @PrashantPimpale

Comment: @vinay Check the posted answer

Answer (score 1):

Because in your template when you reference `task` you are actually referencing the *object*, not a *property* of the object. If the task has a 'name' or 'label' property and you needed to string interpolate the value then you would use `{{ task.name }}` in the template

Answer (score 0):

Inside forloop use:

```
{{task.title}}
```

OR change the class as:

```
export class Task {
  title: string;
  isDone: boolean;
}
```

[`Working Demo`](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uau72w)

Comment: yeah I am also having data in task.component.ts in chrome console, but it is not displaying page. Did i miss anything, i have tried many other solutions, but none worked for me. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

when you need to print the object in your HTML template you just need to convert it to JSON.

```
{{task| json}}
```